# What are the advantages of declaring private members at the end of a class?

Tags: c++

From http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy/cpp/1:

```
class TestBed
{
  public:
    enum StrategyType
    {
        Dummy, Left, Right, Center
    };
    TestBed()
    {
        strategy_ = NULL;
    }
    void setStrategy(int type, int width);
    void doIt();
  private:
    Strategy *strategy_;
};
```

Note how the private members have been declared at the end. I have seen this programming style at several other places, but somehow I find declaring private members first easier to read.

Are there any advantages of declaring private members at the end of the class, like done above?

Comment: It's just a matter of style.  No benefits either way

Comment: The only benefit this would have is that if someone is looking through your headers, he can see the interesting public members first. This is only an issue if your classes are really long, which you should probably avoid.

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this is whatever you prefer, you probably want to try and keep all public/protected/private together.  It may be just me, but some public then some private then more public, etc. is harder to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When reading a class declaration the most important thing is the public interface and so it makes sense to go at the top. Your eyes shouldn't be drawn to the private members which hold the implementation.

It really doesn't matter much though. Pick a style (or be given one) and stick with it.

Actually, the only thing I can really think of it changing is the order of initialization of members. That seldom matters though.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no, and I don't see why you should have benefits.

It's just a matter of personal taste, you should try to understand where your eyes prefer to look for them and stick that way.

Answer (score 0):

In the original C++ implementation, all the members had to be declared at the beginning of a class, or code in the method definitions  couldn't see them. The ability to define members at the end was added later, and some folks, relishing their new freedom, adopted this style and stuck with it. Either location makes sense, though.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring private members at the end of a class is definitely a naming convention. Not required but easy to read since it's common to see them listed after public members.

However, you can also omit the "private:" part and just declare your private members outside of the public ones. If you do not put these variables under the "private:" part and just declare them outside (in this case, above) the "public:" area, they should automatically be defaulted to private.